# Django ORM, one parameter different

Tags: python, django

I am in a project where i am doing this

```
mt = Model.objects.get(pk=2)
if mt.quantity > 0 and not ModelClass.objects.filter(a=mt.a, b = mt.b, c=mt.c, low__lte=mt.rate).exists():
    ----Do Something
elif mt.quantity < 0 and not ModelClass.objects.filter(a=mt.a, b=mt.b, c=mt.c, high__gte=mt.rate).exists():
   ---Do Same as above
```

Is there any other Pythonic way of to do this.

This question is just for academic interest, as my objective is being achieved with the above.

Thank You.

EDIT:
I can use OR also for it, but i would like to know whether this can be achieved in a compact manner.

EDIT 2: The two models i.e. Model and ModelClass are not related by any foreign key.

Comment: Is `Model` and `ModelClass` somehow related?

Comment: they are not related i.e. no foreign key. but there are more filters in this. I will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most readable way without repeating the same filters in every clause is probably this:

```
mt = Model.objects.get(pk=2)
qs = ModelClass.objects.filter(a=mt.a, b = mt.b, c=mt.c)
if mt.quantity > 0 and not qs.filter(low__lte=mt.rate).exists():
    ----Do Something
elif mt.quantity < 0 and not qs.filter(high__gte=mt.rate).exists():
    ---Do Same as above
```

If you want to use some Python-specific constructs you could also just construct the keyword arguments for the `filter()`:

```
kwargs = dict(a=mt.a, b=mt.b, c=mt.c)
if mt.quantity > 0:
    kwargs.update({'low__lte': mt.rate})
if mt.quantity < 0:
    kwargs.update({'high__gte': mt.rate})
if ModelClass.objects.filter(**kwargs).exists():
    # do some stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

You could factor out the common parts of the filter into a queryset, to prevent duplication:

```
query = ModelClass.objects.filter(a=mt.a, b = mt.b, c=mt.c)

if mt.quantity > 0 and not query.filter(low__lte=mt.rate).exists():
    ----Do Something
elif mt.quantity < 0 and not query.filter(high__gte=mt.rate).exists():
   ---Do Same as above
```

On advantage of using an `or` statement is that you don't duplicate the code in 'Do something'. You could factor out that code into a single method `do_something()` to prevent duplication.

Another way to prevent the duplication is to use a flag:

```
do_something = False
if mt.quantity > 0 and not query.filter(low__lte=mt.rate).exists():
    do_something = True
elif mt.quantity < 0 and not query.filter(a=mt.a, b=mt.b, c=mt.c, high__gte=mt.rate).exists():
   do_something = True

if do_something:
    # do the thing
```

Sometimes it is useful to use dynamic arguments. However, in this case, it would probably make your code more complicated than necessary.

```
query = {}
if mt.quantity > 0:
    query['low__lte'] = mt.rate
elif mt.quantity < 0:
    query['high__gte'] = mt.rate
if mt.quantity != 0 and ModelClass.objects.filter(a=mt.a, b = mt.b, c=mt.c, **query).exists():
    # do something
```

Sometimes, you can use [`Q()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) objects to do complex filters

```
ModelClass.objects.filter(Q(low__lte=mt.rate)|Q(high__gte=mt.rate)).exists():
```

However, that doesn't help you in this case, because you are also checking `mt.quantity` in the if statements.

Comment: there is a typo, filters are duplicated in elif in 1st two.

Comment: Thanks, fixed now.